# What's this logo tattooed on the bottom of a thug's foot?

Tags: dc, batman, video-games, arkham-series

I noticed a logo tattooed on a Blackgate thug's foot in a Batman: Arkham Asylum (PC) predator challenge. Does it signify some organization in the DC universe, or is it something else entirely? I was thinking the League of Assassins, but I can't find a logo for that, and this fellow seemed entirely too inept to qualify.

[image: A Blackgate thug falling in challenge mode]

Comment: Interesting... To me, it looks like an Illuminati symbol, but also very similar to the Neverwinter Nights logo.

Comment: Hm, maybe it's the Quake 3 and NWN logos combined.

Comment: It's the Arkham Asylum branch of the Church of the FSM.

Comment: The Eye of Sauron.

Comment: It looks super familiar to me, but maybe I'm just thinking of some variant on the Sheikah symbol from Zelda: http://zeldawiki.org/Eye_Symbol

Comment: @Paul - It does look quite similar, that's true

Comment: They really did put a lot of detail into that game.

Comment: There were tripod aliens from a children's book that I imagined something like that (they weren't on the cover or anything).  Three solid legs, three tentacles for arms, one eye and a large mouth.  I would've read it in the mid-90s...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As per Paul's comment above, the symbol on the character's foot appears to be a stylised version of the [Sheikah Symbol](http://zelda.wikia.com/wiki/Sheikah) repeatedly used in the Zelda game series.

[image: Sheikah Emblem] [image]

Adding weight to this theory is [an interview](http://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/132540/rocksteadys_sefton_hill_unmasks_.php?page=2) given by Sefton Hill (Game Director for "Batman : Arkham Asylum") in which he describes his key influences as being Metroid **and Zelda**.

> **There are some influences from other games in Batman: Arkham Asylum. You said you didn't necessarily look to other Batman titles, which was
>   probably a good idea for the most part. But can you comment on the
>   specific influences? I see a little bit of BioShock, and a little bit
>   of Eternal Darkness. Can you comment on any of the game influences
>   that you have had in design?**
>
> **SH:** *Like the rest of the design world, I'm a big fan of Zelda and Metroid games, going back for years. They were definitely big
>   influences. I like that sort of approach to design -- giving you a
>   number of different gadgets and abilities that you can use and combine
>   in different ways, and the way that combines and the feeling of being
>   in this complete other world. Those games were definitely a big
>   influence. I played Eternal Darkness and I really liked that. Those
>   guys did a great job with that. They had a sanity system in there that
>   freaked a lot of people out. It was a nice idea.*

[image: Zelda Sheikah]

[image: Zelda Sheikah 2]

Comment: I think Michael's got a point too, about it being a lot like the Neverwinter Nights logo. It's even got the eye looking up.

Comment: I'm not seeing it. Yes, it's an "eye" but that's largely where the similarity ends; http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/7/7a/Neverwinter_Nights_cover.jpg

Comment: It's looking up, and there's three extrusions at the bottom. They don't match up with the zigzags in the tattoo though, while the three triangles of the Sheikah symbol match up better with the squiggles up top.

Comment: @Twon-ha : That's true, but I see no out-of-universe connection, nor does the NWN logo have any lightning coming out of it. It's superficially similar (because it's an eye) but that's about it.